# Identifying Read-Only SQL Statements

Tags: python, sql

I'm using SQLAlchemy to execute SQL statements on a variety of different databases and am trying to find a way to determine whether or not an SQL statement (passed to the connector as a python string). What is the best way to do this reliably for multiple flavours of SQL?

```
raw_query = "SELECT * FROM table"
engine = get_engine(username=db_dict['username'],
                              password=db_dict['password'],
                              db=database,
                              hostname=db_dict['hostname'],
                              port=port,
                              db_type=db_dict['type'])
with engine.connect() as db_conn:
    # query database
    result = db_conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text(raw_query))
```

In the above, what is the best way to check whether the SQL in raw_query will require more than read-only permissions? Or in other words, whether or not it will make changes to the database.

Comment: I don't think there is any tried-and-true way to do this besides ensuring that the username you are using to execute these statements doesn't have access that you don't want it to have. Naively, you could check to make sure the statement starts with `SELECT`. Some regex like `(^SEL|^SELECT)\s` may do the trick, but obviously wouldn't catch something like `SELECT * FROM sometable; UPDATE sometable SET somecolumn=NULL;`.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse

Comment: As a start, you could look for occurrences of UPDATE, INSERT, TRUNCATE, DELETE, DROP, etc.

Comment: Don't forget WITH, VALUES and TABLE as first read-only word.

Comment: SQL Server and Oracle (probably among some others) also support `SELECT INTO`, which can be mutative despite the use of `SELECT`. However - this smells a lot like an XY problem - if you are concerned in some regard about database mutations from otherwise untrusted user input you probably should think about your security architecture a bit more.

Comment: You can `SELECT INTO` variables and collections, but can you `SELECT INTO` a table?  I thought that was `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`

Comment: Of course read-only permissions is the solution to avoid unauthorized updates.

Comment: @jarlh I agree, read-only permissions on the database is the way to ensure only read-only statements are actually executed. I'm just curious to see if/what I can catch at this level, before executing the statement.

Comment: I have a version where I use a regex to identify DROP, GRANT, CREATE, REVOKE, DELETE, etc. This works and I'm wondering if there is any other way to do this without implementing it myself that takes into account all edge cases (column names including these terms, nested statements - some examples already called out in this comment thread), SQL dialects, etc. Not against it, just making sure there isn't already something out there.

Answer (score -2):

In most cases, when you run sql statements via some libraries, you are supposed to get the number of modified fields, created fields or something as a return value.

For example:
updatePayload := bson.M{...}
result, err := db.[tablename].UpdateByID(ctx.Context, updatedID, bson.M{"$set": updatePayload})

if result.ModifiedCount == 0 {
continue
// this means no field was updated.
}

I'm sure there are some similar functionalities SQLAlchemy too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would guess that the OP wants to know _before_ the statements are executed.

Comment: ah... I think so. I've gone through the question again and noticed that it's out of database manipulation scope.. Maybe I should propose a way to use RegExp or something..

Comment: But I think it's impossible to guess if a statement will affect the database before running it... Maybe running the statement first and then perform a kind of rollback if some fields are changed..

Comment: Correct, when I DROP a TABLE for example I get an effected row count of -1. As you rightly pointed identified, I'd like to catch this before executing the statement. I'd be executing it but - for example - warning the user. I'm aware that this needs to ideally taken care of on database-level (ie. the owner should create an RO-account) and the challenge of the question. Have thought of regex, post is to see if there is some other way whereby I don't have to implement the regex, which will ultimately finding strings within strings and as a feeling will be difficult to make bulletproof.